# Karaf command not found exception how to troubleshoot?

Tags: java, shell, karaf

Downloaded karaf 4.0.9 just following getting started doc but keep getting this

```
 org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandNotFoundException: Command not found: feature:install
```

whenever i try to do `feature:install wrapper` from `shell`

Finding it very difficult to find any help or doc how to trouble shoot? is it a permissions thing? I chowned everything to the same user for simplicity...

Is distribution missing a library? Where do i get it/put it?

New to karaf... Following this: http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/#_installation

Just trying to get some basic JDBC/JMS stuff working, install drivers, recieve some msgs, query db, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spent a few hours of reading docs + trial and error to figure this out:

```
 ssh karaf@localhost -p 8101
```

Will get you full admin shell, apparently this isn't available if you just `./shell` from `KARAF_HOME/bin`

Answer (score 0):

You can check your configurations in **users.properties** in **karaf/etc** folder .

Open karaf shell using **admin** rights.

Start Karaf shell from its **bin** folder.

Now run karaf console using below command.

> **ssh username@localhost -p8101**

now you can run any command of karaf shell.